# Sencha Touch issue - connecting a list to other list

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, back-button, tabpanel

I wish to call a list from a list.
I do not want to use a nested list cause my data size is just too big.

How can I call, onItemDisclosure, a new list/card/panel? How does it working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a new panel with another `Ext.List` in it. set onItemDisclosure to a handler that reveals the new panel, and bind the store to the new list accordingly. The code would somewhat look like this:

```
app.views.TopList = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {
  initComponent: function() {
    // some code
    Ext.apply(this, {
      onItemDisclosure: function () {
        app.views.subList.bindStore(app.stores.storeWithProperData);
        app.views.viewport.setActiveItem(app.views.subList);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @DaNmarner.
I used to do almost the same way as u do. The only diference is that I'm using new Ext.List({}) instead of Ext.extend(Ext.List, {}). 
I updated my question with URL to my app and my code. I will appericiate if you could take a look at it.
I am able to navigate to the new list, but all my layout breaks.... 
I'll be happy if you could see it there. Thank you, Shlomi.

Answer (score 1):

Add the parent and child lists into a panel with card layout. On **onItemDisclosure** function of the parent list, load the child list with **setActiveItem** method().

Hope it will help..

Comment: Thank you @heyjii.
I have tried to implement this idea, but |I guess i'm doing something wrong. I updated my post with code examples and url to my app. I will appreciate if you could take a look there.
Thanks, Shlomi.